# ¿Cómo traducir 'I am her husband'?

Tags: gramática, pronombres

I am learning with duolingo.com and had to translate `I am her husband`.

I thought the correct translation is `Soy le marido`, but duolingo says `Soy su marido` is correct.

Which is correct? The sentence `Le doy las flores a ella` is fine, isn't it? So `Soy le marido a ella` is incorrect?

How do I use these pronouns?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Duolinguo is right: the correct way to translate it is **`soy su marido`**.

`le` is a personal pronoun, whereas `su` is an possessive adjective. Since you want to show the "possession", you have to use `su`.

Note that if we weren't using the pronoun, we would say:

> **Le** doy las flores -> Doy las flores **a ella**

and

> Soy **su** marido -> Soy marido **de ella**

meaning that in each case, `le` and `su` have a different meaning. The fact that in English both are used as `her` does not imply that they are also used like this in Spanish.

Comment: Isn't **su** a possessive *pronoun*? **Her** is in English.

Comment: No, it is a possessive adjective: http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=su